# Netca command not found Oracle 12c (silent mod)

Tags: oracle-12c, listener

i'm new on the Oracle's world, the installation it was easy and good, but , I dont know where is the problem here.

[image]

Comment: I've always used the Oracle supplied code to set variables. ( `. /usr/local/bin/oraenv` )

Answer (score 0):

run

```
find /u01/app/oracle -name netca
```

It should return a netca in a bin folder inside $ORACLE_HOME.  In your environment script, I see ORACLE_HOME ending in ../12.2.0.1/db_1.  Is that where Oracle's bin folder is located?

Comment: I did a new install and now I got a new error, I left he image above. I'll try your your tip. Many thanks for you attencion Gerard.

Comment: Libclntsh.so.12.1 has failed to build or is an invalid link. What version of Linux are you trying this on? What's "silent mod"? Why an old version of Oracle?

Comment: Fyi: to build libclntsh.so you run genclntsh

Comment: I´m new in ORACLE world, so I´m learning how to install, I did on 19c, worked fine, now I started to learning Oracle 12c. I have Red Hat 8.4.  Silent mode, because people told me to learn this way, because working on servers it´s different to install Oracle.

Comment: Perhaps you took advice from the wrong people. I always used Orainstall, the graphical interface, to install Oracle.  You should succeed on Redhat, but I'm not sure about which version.  Search on the net for prerequisites for Oracle 12c, and advice.  I don't see what is to be gained by learning an older version.